# Wicket: addOrReplace() inside Form's onSubmit()

Tags: java, wicket, wicket-6

I have a wicket `Form` inside a page, declared like this:

```
protected void onBeforeRender() {
    Form<Void> frm = new Form<Void>("frm") {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            protected void onSubmit() {
                super.onSubmit();
                doSomething();
            }
        };

    //other stuff...
    addOrReplace(frm);
}
```

`doSomething` is a method in the page itself. Inside that method I do:

```
private void doSomething(){
    //stuff...
    addOrReplace(new Label("labelID", "Some text"));
}
```

The problem is that the call to `addOrReplace` does not work. I don't see the text added to the page. It only shows up if I refresh.

How can I make calls to `addOrReplace` work from inside a `onSubmit()` callback?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you're working with AjaxButtons. You'll have to update the component or any of its parents to make the change visible in the browser:

```
ajaxRequestTarget.add(frm);
```

Remember to call #setOutputMarkupId(true) on the component you want to update via Ajax:

```
frm.setOutputMarkupId(true);
addOrReplace(frm);
```

To get hold of the AjaxRequestTarget you could override `AjaxButton#onSubmit(AjaxRequestTarget, Form)` and call doSomething from there - passing the AjaxRequestTarget to any method which has to update something.

Alternatively you can always call #getRequestCycle().find(AjaxRequestTarget.class) to get the current AjaxRequestTarget.

Comment: Where exactly should I put these instructions? The Form's onSubmit() method does not have any parameters. Where do I get "ajaxTargetRequest" from?

Comment: Ok, so instead of using the From's "onSubmit()" I should use the AjaxSubmitLink's onSubmit(), right? (I'm using an AjaxSubmitLink to generate the submit button)

Comment: Yes, this is how I would do it.